# Show $U \otimes V$ is an irreducible G-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, modules

Let $G$ is some group and $U$ is an irriducible $G$-module over the complex numbers. Now if $V$ is a $G$-module of dimension 1, I would like to prove $U \otimes V$ is an irriducible $G$-module.

My knowledge of tensor products is lacking..

Comment: How is the tensor product defined? Specifically, how is the action of the group on the tensor product defined? (note: This is meant to be hints towards a solution, not just idle questions).

Comment: Do you mean $U\otimes_{\Bbb C}V$?

Comment: @Berci I'm not familiar with that notation

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I can see $U \otimes V$ is a $G$-module.. but I can't seen to find a way to make it irreducible

Comment: Take a closer look at how the structure as a $G$-module is given, consider a submodule and see that this gives you a submodule of $U$ in a nice way.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I may have said too much...

Comment: @SammyBlack In my opinion not by a great deal at least. You have left the most important part to the OP, which seems like a fine way to do it.

Comment: If the tensor is over $\Bbb C$ (what else could it be?), then isn't it simply the case that $U\cong U\otimes V$ for $\dim V=1$, and the $G$-action is obtained by this isomorphism?

Comment: @Berci only as vector spaces, not as $G$-modules.

Comment: @user68654 : related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745262

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $\{u_1, u_2, \dots \}$ is a basis for the irreducible $G$-module $U$.  Since $V$ is $1$-dimensional, $V = \mathbb{C}v$ for some nonzero $v \in V$.

Then, a basis for $U \otimes V$ is $\{u_1 \otimes v, u_2 \otimes v, \dots \}$.  Any $G$-submodule of $U \otimes V$ will be of the form $W \otimes V$, where $W \le U$.  Why?  How does $G$ act in the tensor product?

As $U$ is irreducible, either $W = 0$ or $W = U$.  As a consequence, either $W \otimes V = 0 \otimes V = 0$ or $W \otimes V = U \otimes V$.  Therefore $U \otimes V$ is irreducible.

Comment: What do you mean by $W\leq U$?

Comment: @SimonSMN $W \leq U$ denotes $W$ being a submodule of $U$. This notation is often used with subgroups, vector subspaces, etc., basically, anywhere where we want to indicate that it's not only subset containment $W \subseteq U$.

Comment: All right. I'm studying representations and subrepresentations. I did not manage to solve not the question in the way you indicated. I instead followed Tobias Tildetofts comment. In general, is there any relation between $U\bigotimes V$ and $W\bigotimes V$ for $U$ a subrepresentation of $W$? Because I don't see it. The latter is a quotient of the free module of functions $W\times V\to R$ whereas the former is a quotient of the free module of functions $U\times V\to R$.

Answer (score 6):

Another, definitively less elegant, method to solving this is to recall that a representation $\rho:G\to\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is irreducible if and only if $\langle\chi_\rho,\chi_\rho\rangle=1$, and that if $\rho,\psi:G\to\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ are a pair of representations then

$$\chi_{\rho\otimes\psi}=\chi_\rho\chi_\psi$$

With this in mind, let $\rho:G\to\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ be an irreducible representation and $\psi:G\to S^1$ a character. Then,

$$\begin{aligned}\langle\chi_{\rho\otimes\psi},\chi_{\rho\otimes\psi}\rangle &= \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in g}|\chi_{\rho\times\psi}(g)|^2\\ &= \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} |\chi_\rho(g)|^2|\chi_\psi(g)|^2\\ &= \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}|\chi_\rho(g)|^2\\&=1\end{aligned}$$

where we used the fact that $\chi_\psi(g)=\psi(g)\in S^1=\{z:|z|=1\}$ for all $g$, and the last step was achieved using the fact that $\rho$ was irreducible.

This is much less elegant, and much more difficult than is needed, but it's always useful to remember this brute-force method of attacking irreducibility over $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3):

If $V$ has dimension $1$ then it is *invertible* in the sense that there's another module $V'$ such that $V \otimes V'$ is isomorphic to the trivial representation.  (A good exercise is to work out what this $V'$ is.)  If you have a submodule $W \subset U \otimes V$ then $W \otimes V' \subset U$, so any submodule of $U \otimes V$ gives a submodule of $U$ with the same dimension.